# Do targets exist in android as it exists in iOS?

Tags: android, ios

In iOS we've targets, which is a custom app compilation for a customer, like custom logo, or custom contents. Do this exist in android?

I do not feel like copying whole project, as 80% of the methods are exactly the same.

Comment: Not exactly. Maybe you could accomplish by maintaining a config file whose values you can change and based upon those values you trigger a build which would generate separate builds as per your config inputs. Again it totally depends on the way you develop.

Comment: I've thought about performing some svn exernals to packages, but as soon as I've to edit one of them, it's becoming a mess.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I think there is no easy way to do that at least in android. and there is no existing feature similar to IOS's target in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Android Gradle build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) supports creating [build variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) with e.g. different resources easily.

With the older Ant/Eclipse-based build tooling, people often rolled their own scripts for resource customization.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in Android, as they are the closest thing to accessing and managing shareable, reusable resources which I think you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Using gradle build system you are able to use [`Build Variant`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) which is combination of `Build Type`(e.g. debug, release) and `Flavor`(e.g. free, paid)

`Build Variant`: debugFree, debugPaid, releaseFree, releasePaid